# How to set AMP image Align Center

Tags: amp-html

How to set in amp page like follow?

```
<p align="center"><img src="img/LOCK1.png" width="40"> <img src="img/lock2.png"  width="40"> <img src="img/LOCK3.png" width="40"></p>
```

Thank You!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For amp you need to use amp-img tag

> AMP HTML files don't support the normal HTML img tag. With amp-img AMP provides a powerful replacement.

```
<p>
    <amp-img src="img/LOCK1.png"  layout="fixed" width="40" height="40" alt="Lock1"></amp-img>
    <amp-img src="img/lock2.png"  layout="fixed"  width="40" height="40" alt="Lock2"></amp-img>
    <amp-img src="img/LOCK3.png"  layout="fixed" width="40" height="40" alt="Lock3"></amp-img>
</p>
```

Please refer : [**amp-img**](https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-img/)

> You can not use inline and external css in amp

You could use internal css with following syntax

```
<style amp-custom>
  p {
    text-align: center;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Thank You! How about the align="center" ?

Comment: check my updated answer, please let me know if still you are facing any issue

Comment: @BachchaSingh Thank You ! I was also looking for the same solution. You save my Day :)

Comment: note that amp-img element has closing tag, unlike img which has not, 
and specifying height="40" width="40" without the layout attribute implies a fixed layout for the image, ie. layout="fixed" with aspect ratio 1:1,
<amp-img src="img/LOCK1.png" layout="fixed" width="40" height="40" alt="Lock1"></amp-img>

Comment: Changing the layout to `intrinsic` fixed the image not centering issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

Borrowing much from @Bachcha Singh's answer, I only succeeded when I did it as shown below after adding a div around the image code and the inline css code just below the image AMP code. This is how I managed to center my image on my AMP page

```
<div class="img-wrapper">
<amp-img src="https://jomutech.com/dispJomutechIcon.png height="50" width="250" alt="Logo">
</amp-img>
</div>

<style amp-custom>
  div.img-wrapper {
    text-align: center;
  }
</style>
```