# How to integrate AMP (Accelerated Mobile Pages) on your existing REACT website?

Tags: reactjs, amp-html

I'm currently working on a PWA app which is written in React.js and I'm using VScode editor. I have read the AMP docs in which it is written that replace your HTML media tags with AMP equivalent AMP media tags. But when I'm replacing `<img src="" alt="" />` with `<amp-img src="" alt="" ></amp-img>`, my vscode editor is auto correcting it to `<amp-img src="" alt="" />` which is resulting in

> status: AMP Validation FAILED

and in web-view, my images are not visible due to this issue.

Please help.

Comment: <amp-img src="" alt="" /> this is also correct you need to add the layout, width and height of image : https://stackoverflow.com/a/43486648/5635098

Comment: @BachchaSingh No, it's not correct syntax, in AMP docs it is clearly mentioned that closing tags are mandatory for amp-img and I have also tried to run my project by using <amp-img src=" " alt=" " /> but in place of the image, it's showing empty space.

Comment: <amp-img src=" " alt=" " /> should be <amp-img src=" " alt=" " layout=" " height=" " width=" "   /> these all needed. Visit this link I have checked : https://preview.ibb.co/juHnun/amp_pass.png

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Bachcha Singh's comment, you may want to check this [link](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/fundamentals/validate) to validate AMP pages. Also, you can't just convert your site into an AMP just by replacing few tags. Your site must follow AMP HTML [specification](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/spec). Check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45820307/images-are-not-visible-on-amp-pages). You may also check this [tutorial](https://www.ampproject.org/latest/blog/putting-the-amp-in-progressive-web-amps-meet-the-shadowreader/) on how to combine AMP and PWA.

Comment: I have already followed all the rules which are present in this link https://www.ampproject.org/docs/fundamentals/validate and also on this link https://www.ampproject.org/docs/fundamentals/spec after that only I'm asking this question. but I think https://www.ampproject.org/latest/blog/putting-the-amp-in-progressive-web-amps-meet-the-shadowreader/ this link could be useful for me. but I have to study it deeply and understand the projects given in it.